# Tables are different accessing database with SQLAlchemy and psql

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

The tables in my PostgreSQL database are different when I connect with psql and SQLAlchemy. The results are not the same when doing a simple SELECT using the following two methods. Using psql results in an old version of the data without any data, while I am able to update and fetch the most recent data using SQLAlchemy.

psql method:

```
bash $ psql $DATABASE_URL
user=> SELECT * FROM scraped_data; /* This results in an empty table! */
 id | user_id |            date            |  state   | progress |
```

SQLAlchemy method:

```
# Where DATABASE_URL has asyncpg driver specified.
ENGINE = create_async_engine(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"], future=True) 

async def get_scraped_data():
    async with ENGINE.connect() as conn:
        result = await conn.execute(
            text("SELECT * FROM scraped_data ")
        return result.all() # This works, and I get the expected data!
```

When I query the database using SQLAlchemy, I am able to get the most recent data.

Why is there a difference in the tables when using psql and when using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: can you show os.environ["DATABASE_URL"]?

Comment: When connecting with SQLAlchemy + asyncpg: postgresql+asyncpg://username:password@ec2-3-209-124-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/database

When connecting with psql: postgresql://username:password@ec2-3-209-124-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/database